# Examples of unbounded continuous function $f:Q\cap[0,1]\rightarrow R$

Tags: continuity

I want to find examples of unbounded continuous function $f:Q\cap[0,1]\rightarrow R$
I am thinking $\frac{1}{1+n}$ may satisfy but not quite sure.
And if there are I want to see other examples too.
Thanks!

Comment: $$\begin{split}
\lim_{n\to1^-}\frac{1}{1+n}&=\frac{1}{2}\\
\lim_{n \to 0^+} \frac{1}{1+n} &= 1
\end{split}$$

Moreover $f(n) = \frac{1}{1+n}$ is monotonic on [0;1].

Comment: Ok, then $n^2$ will do?

Comment: No! Why it should? Look at Hamou answer.

Comment: Ok. I was stupid. I don't know why I came up with those. I wasn't able to find an example anyways but those are not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $a\in [ 0,1]$ s.t $a\notin\Bbb Q $ and $ f(x)=\dfrac{ 1}{ x-a}$